# Why a set android Image disappears?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to post an  image captured from `Camera` , i'm using following code

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CODE_PHOTO_TAKE);
```

**inside onActivityResult i wrote this code**

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
mainImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

**Updated**

```
<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="8"
     android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

This code works fine on almost all devices but i am facing problem in **LG Lucid VS840** where by default camera mode is landscape. After capturing image, if i press ok button, image remains visible for seconds and then disappears. At that time, I literally can see camera mode changing.

I had written  `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` but it did not work.

You can find video link here  :  [Link](http://youtu.be/P4X_oAdLMtc)

I have tested this code in following devices where it worked .

- Sony xperia U
- Samsung Galaxy Nexus
- Motorola droid RAZR
- Samsung ACE

Answer (score 0):

What's your target SDK version? You need to supply `screenSize` as well if that's above 13.

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

See the note for `orientation`.

Comment: Cool, any difference when `screenSize` is added?